# Replacing/Removing value for a given key in a dynamic value in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there any way in Kusto using which we can replace value for a specific key within a dynamic value in Kusto? Either replace value or even delete the whole key value pair if required?

**UPDATE**

Say we have the following dynamic value in a table:-

```
   { 
      "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num1":1.33,
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
    }
```

Now I want to get rid of the key value pair for the key `Num1` so that the resulting output will be the following:-

```
   { 
      "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
    }
```

If that is not possible even the following masking can work as a solution too, by masking I mean whenever key Num1 appears in the dynamic value , it will be assigned a fixed value (0 in this example) for all the rows:-

```
  { 
      "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num1":0,
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
    }
```

The value could be anything string or number, here in this example I have used number but this could be anything.

Comment: the output should be dynamic value itself

Comment: even if we can filter out a specific key (and whatever is the value for the key) from the dynamic value and return a new value as a result, that will work too

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: updated the post with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

```
let t = datatable(mystring:string)
[
'
{     "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num1":180,           
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
}
'
];
t
| project myjson = parse_json(mystring)
| project Num2=tostring(myjson.Num2), City=tostring(myjson.City), SectionA=tostring(myjson.SectionA)
| extend newColumn=strcat("\"City\":","\"",City,"\", \"Num2\":","", Num2,", \"SectionA\":","", SectionA)
```

The result:

[image]

---

Please try the code below to see if it can solves the issue:

```
let t = datatable(mystring:string)
[
'
{     "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num1":180,           
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
}
'
];
t
| project myjson = parse_json(mystring)
| project Num2=tostring(myjson.Num2), City=tostring(myjson.City), SectionA=tostring(myjson.SectionA)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: yes but this is splitting the end result in 3 separate columns, I wanted a single column result as shown in my example.

Comment: @Dhiraj, oh, I will take a try and update this later.

Comment: there is one challenge here though. Now we need to know name of every key value pair that will appear. We might not have that information. I only know the key that I want to exclude. The logic you provided explicitly selects all the other values excluding the one we want to remove. Is there any way to only remove a key that we know we want to remove, we don't know what other keys might appear.

Comment: So all we know is name and path (within json) of the key.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way for setting a value in a Kusto dynamic dictionary \ bag with unknown keys (or with too many keys to list in a query) is using the new `bag_merge` function:

```
let t = dynamic({ 
      "SectionA":{ 
                 "Prop1":"abcd",
                 "Prop2":"efgh",
                 "Prop3":"ahd32",
                 "category":"main"
                 },
      "Num1":1.33,
      "Num2":33.8,
      "City":"New York"
    });

print bag_merge(dynamic({"Num1":0}), t)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [bag_remove_keys()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-remove-keys-function) function removes keys and associated values from a dynamic property-bag. The only limitation is the keys on the nested levels aren't supported.

```
datatable(input:dynamic) [
    dynamic({ 
        "SectionA":{ 
                    "Prop1":"abcd",
                    "Prop2":"efgh",
                    "Prop3":"ahd32",
                    "category":"main"
                    },
        "Num1":1.33,
        "Num2":33.8,
        "City":"New York"
    }) ] | extend result=bag_remove_keys(input, dynamic(['Num1']))
```